# Recepient cannot see facebook request from notification

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app where I allow the user to select from their facebook friends and send them a message. This is the code I am using:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");
WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,
    Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(
        new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
            }

        }).build();
    requestsDialog.show();
```

The user picks from a list of friends and the message gets sent successfully. The problem is when the friend gets the notification that they have received a message--they try to access the message from the pull down notifications and instead of showing the message, the Facebook app just shows a loading symbol indefinitely (or, at best, if I send a message to the same user it shows up intermittently). If the user goes to their notification center, the message is visible there, so they've clearly received it.

What could account for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the app domain and the Website With Facebook Login in the Facebook app settings seems to have fixed the issue.